# When a module over a principal ring is free

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative, principal ideal ring *that may have zero-divisors*. Is there still a structure theory for the finitely-generated modules over $R$?

In particular, I would like to know a condition that makes a finitely-generated $R$-module $M$ free. My guess is that this would be equivalent to $M$ not having "too much torsion", in the sense that a torsion element should only be annihilated by zero-divisors in $R$, but I am not sure whether such a condition is sufficient.

Comment: A finitely generated module over a PIR is a direct sum of cyclic modules.